# Kill old javascript and load new ones after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to stop executing some JavaScript code after doing a new Ajax request and after that I would like to load new code.

Here is what I did so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../files/php/user_actions/user_checkout.php' + '?rel=tab',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#content").html(
            $('<div />').html(data).find("#content").html()
        );

        //execute JavaScript
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); //Replace "document" with the received data?!
        for (var n = 0; n <= a.length; n++) {
            var source = $(a[n]).attr('src');
            if (source !== undefined) { //only use the scripts containing a src-attr
                console.log(source);
                $(a[n]).remove(); //remove objects from the DOM
                $.getScript(source); //execute the scripts
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *"stop executing some code"* or *"kill old javascript"*? Question is not clear

Comment: After I redirect the user from a page, I want to use different JavaScript code for a different page. 
Because if the user return back to the previous page and presses a button the page will double the http request every time the JavaScript code gets imported and executed again.

Comment: Please [edit question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43375647/edit) with a far more detailed explanation of your situation if you want help

Comment: @Hexdec JavaScript code loaded through `<script>` tags runs once and is then done. Anything that follows are event listeners, which are technically modifications to the page. That's sort of like mixing sugar and salt: there is no "undo all" button for that - you'll have to write a script that manually reverses every single thing the previous script has done. See also: [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answere is, there is no way doing it...

You have to reset the connection the clear the ram from loaded scripts by redirect yourself from the current page.

I put together all scripts and made them individual so I have loaded all scripts at once so I can change the source of the website dynamically.